# Basic Open Problems in Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Hello I was wondering if there exists open problems in functional analysis that don't require too much machinary for studying them, I mean, problems that don't require high level prerequisites.. Does anyone know any of them:

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search gave this (from 2004), which looks like what you wanted(?): You'll have to check if they have been solved since then.

http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-20-1/20J1Masly.pdf

Also, you can try here:

http://aimpl.org/

Comment: I liked that paper, it sounds there's some interesting problems in there =D Thanks