# open problems regarding functions

Tags: functions, big-list, open-problem

I am looking for some open problems regarding functions. Problems like,

*Whether a function satisfying some properties say, X,Y,Z, exists or not, is unknown.*

Like there is no function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=h(x)$ where  $h(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $h(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$.

Or if $J=\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ denote the set of irrational numbers. There is no continuous map $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq J$ and $f(J) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

What are some interesting properties for which researchers are looking to find mappings that satisfies them.

Comment: This is a little bit vague, since any problem can be phrased in terms of a function.  e.g., is there a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and so that $f(x)$ is less than the size of the set $\{ n < x: n \text{ is a twin prime}\}$?  This is equivalent to the twin prime conjecture...

Comment: It would help if you were a lot more specific about what kind of functions you are interested in.

Comment: An earlier, related question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238680/basic-open-problems-in-functional-analysis

Comment: Is really the problem with $J$ open (until I miss some point) ? if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continous, then $f(\mathbb Q)$ is countable, but $f(J)$ is countable by hypothesis. It follow that $f(\mathbb R)$ is countable, connected and not reduced to a point : contradiction.

Comment: no it is not open, but there is no such function is proveable, I asked for such questions which are open now. It was just a sample [solved] example , I put in

Answer (score 1):

At the [Open Problem Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/criterion_for_boundedness_of_power_series), Andreas Rudinger has posted this question: Give a necessary and sufficient condition on the sequence $a_n$ such that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ is bounded for all real $x$.